# Objective-C: How can i access another ViewController and change UI in it?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to navigate to another view and change its UI.

I manage to access to the controller method "hideElements", 
but all the elements are **"NIL"** and it doesnt change anything.

(When i access the ViewController.m regular with no navigation then the properties are not NIL)

**Why is that and How can i solve it?**

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (void)hideElements:(NSString *)identifier{
    [_agreeButton setHidden:TRUE];
    [_noThankButton setHidden:TRUE];
    [self cleanButtons];
}
```

**ViewController2.h**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@property (nonatomic) ViewController *myViewController;
```

**ViewController2.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      NSString *identifire = [sender text];
      ViewController* vc = (ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
      [vc hideElements:identifire];
}
```

**ScreenShot:**
[image]

Comment: Are the elements created from outlets?

Comment: Yes they are buttons created in storyboard

Comment: I'm confused as to why you are instantiating the view controller in `prepareForSegue`. You should be able to access it through the `segue`'s `destination` property.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: `ViewController* vc = (ViewController*)segue.destination;`

Comment: well i'vw fixed it, (see it in code), but still objects are nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171203/discussion-between-dudeman-and-eli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is the view controller's view (and subviews including outlets) haven't been created by the time you are calling `hideElements`. So you can do a couple of things

1)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  NSString *identifire = [sender text];
      ViewController* vc = (ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
      vc.view;
      [vc hideElements:identifire];
}
```

2)

ViewController2.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  NSString *identifire = [sender text];
      ViewController* vc = (ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
      vc.shouldHideElements = YES;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if (self.shouldHideElements) {
        [self hideElements];
    }
}
```

Comment: i've added [vc view]; before calling hideElements, Working Perfectly!